# Jackson type resolving for heterogeneous data

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a data like this :

```
[ 
  {
   "type":"animal"
   "numlegs":4
  }, {
   "type":"car"
   "country":"usa"
  }
]
```

I want that to be parsed into the following classes :

```
public class Animal {
    int numLegs;
}

public class Car {
    string country;
}
```

What is the best way to tell jackson that the class type is based on the value of a property in the JsonObject?

I have went through a lot of examples which talks about using `JsonTypeInfo` and `JsonSubTypes` annotation but that doesn't fit well here as there is no abstract class common to both the objects.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I cannot change the JSON data.

Comment: That wouldn't work anyway. Jackson would have no knowledge of your class to do a reverse lookup.